# iOS: Prevent touch from propagating up to SKScene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm working on an iPad game using SpriteKit, and I use a UIView object atop the SKScene. The UIViews have a gesture recognizer setup up and this works fine, however, the SKScene::touchesBegan(…) method also gets called and I'd like to prevent it from being called when the UIView is touched. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps setting userInteractionEnabled to no when the UIView is on top of the SKScene?

self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;